# Docker daemon (not containers) can't read environment variables

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

Trying to configure a container running outside of GCP to log to Google Cloud Platform (StackDriver). One requirement is that the Docker daemon is able to locate the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` so it can authenticate. One would assume that the following would work, but it doesn't:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/local/keys/project-1.json docker run --log-driver=gcplogs ...
```

That outputs:

```
ERROR: for api Cannot start service api:
       failed to initialize logging driver: google: could not find default credentials.
       See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
       for more information.
```

Haven't found any documentation on how to set that directly on `daemon.json`, but I don't want that either because I might have different containers logging to different GCP projects.

I've tried this on Mac (docker desktop) and Debian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is question that keeps coming back. What is happening here is that environment variable *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS* is loaded by the system docker daemon. System daemons don't see the environment variables set in the user login. What you need to do is set the *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS* at the system level.

Here is how to do that in Ubuntu(Systemd):

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

Create **/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/env.conf** with the following content:

```
[Service]
Environment="GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/file.json"
```

Apply the changes.

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Once done restart docker/containerd daemons

```
$ sudo systemctl restart containerd
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Test the gcplogs driver

```
docker run --log-driver=gcplogs --log-opt gcp-project="my-project" hello-world
```

Comment: That's such a terrible solution because now the entire vm can only use a single GCP key. What if I have two containers that need different access within the same GCP project? Instead of using two specific keys for each of them, I would need to create a key with broad permissions and reuse it, not to mention that the entire VM is limited to forever having access to only one key.

Comment: The problem is not with the solution but with the driver. Driver can access only system set variables. Each vm should be running only one docker service and the environment variable is applied at the service level not the container level.

Comment: You can always override this variable in docker run commands using the --env option. You could also override this in the user level with no impact what so ever.

Comment: That's the whole point of my question. Overriding the env option doesn't work.

Comment: I meant for gcplogs there is nothing you can do. Blame the plugin. For other stuff you continue to use as is.

Comment: I get it. Thanks for the help.